# Add 1000+ faces in the single "FaceList" in Microsoft Face API

Tags: android, ios, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I want to add more than 1000 faces in the single `"FaceList"` instead of creating 64 different face lists.

I will have more than **100,000+** users be added in one group and then want to use `"Find Similar"` API from that same `"FaceList"`.

As there is a limit of adding only 64 Face Lists per subscription and 1000 faces can be added per Face List, how can I achieve this?